# XGBOOST faster than random forest?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am doing kaggle inclass challege of bosten hosing prices and learnt that XGBoost is faster than RandomForest but when implemented was slower.i Want to ask when XGBoost becomes faster and when RandomForest??.I am new to machine learning and need your help.Thanking in advance

Comment: For most reasonable cases, xgboost will be significantly slower than a properly parallelized random forest. If you're new to machine learning, I would suggest understanding the basics of decision trees before you try to start understanding boosting or bagging.

Comment: Thanku @PMende i will follow ur guide

Answer (score 0):

Mainly, the parameters you choose have strong impact in the speed of your algorithm, (e.g learning rate, depth of the tree, number of features etc.), there's a trade-off between accuracy and speed, so i suggest you put the parameters you've chosen for every model and see how to change it to get faster performance with reasonable accuracy.